# Joomla register new user doen't work

Tags: registration, joomla2.5

I'm trying to create new user but for unknown reason it doesn't work. After inserting required information for registration and by clicking submit, blank page is shown, and after inserting required data for creating a new user in the administrator panel this error text is shown:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant Mkrl - assumed 'Mkrl' in /home/shopping/public_html/libraries/phpmailer/phpmailer.php on line 2322

Notice: Use of undefined constant lkFxM4 - assumed 'lkFxM4' in /home/shopping/public_html/libraries/phpmailer/phpmailer.php on line 2323

Notice: Use of undefined constant qdco5Up - assumed 'qdco5Up' in /home/shopping/public_html/libraries/phpmailer/phpmailer.php on line 2323

Notice: Use of undefined constant kqoo_uwuw_ouok_qzzsy - assumed 'kqoo_uwuw_ouok_qzzsy' in /home/shopping/public_html/libraries/phpmailer/phpmailer.php on line 2324

Notice: Use of undefined constant well_wsgz_vwnw_mwrmy - assumed 'well_wsgz_vwnw_mwrmy' in /home/shopping/public_html/libraries/phpmailer/phpmailer.php on line 2324

Notice: Undefined index: EahdNfBKEH in /home/shopping/public_html/libraries/phpmailer/phpmailer.php on line 2325
```

What can be the problem!

Comment: i think this link help you http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=431&t=769438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site has been hacked!

Check your libraries/phpmailer/phpmailer.php. It should contain no more than 1909 lines. The extra lines are malicious code.

Also, check your INSTALL.php. It may also contain code.

I also had to clean up my /tmp directory.

Then you should go through this checklist http://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced